# Salvar dados do banco em array?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tenho um banco de dados onde salvo e-mail e nome de arquivos anexados por usuários, que podem anexar mais de um arquivo, e gostaria de mostrar todos os arquivos que o usuário anexou na tela, eu pensei em salvar em array e usar o var_dump pra mostrar, porém não está sendo salvo no array, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso ou do que está errado em meu código?

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once('conecta.php');
  $resultado = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM arquivos WHERE email_vol = '$email'");
  while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    var_dump($resultado);
  }
?>
```

Comment: o `var_dump()` precisa ser em `$dados` não em `$resultado`

Comment: @rray Mesmo dessa forma ele não mostra nada!

Comment: `$email` se tem algum valor? faltou passar a conexão como primeiro argumento no `mysqli_query()`

Comment: @rray entendi, agora deu certo sim, tava realmente faltando passar a conexão, muito obrigado!!

Comment: haha pois é as vezes aquele **i** fica esquecido :)